# how do i add in mootools an onComplete event on a morph attached to a mouseleave?

Tags: mootools, mouseleave

here is my code:

```
$('myButton').addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
       $('myImage').setStyle('display','block');
       $('myImage').morph({
            'duration': 500,
            'transition': Fx.Transitions.Sine.in,
            'opacity': 1,
            'top': -205
       });
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
       $('myImage').morph({
            'opacity': 0,
            'top': -175,
            'onComplete': hidemyImage
       });
    }   
});

function hidemyImage() {
    $('myImage').setStyle('display','none') 
}
```

the **onComplete** inside the **mouseleave** does not work as expected... it hides the image immediately when i move away from myButton instead of hiding it after the morph has finished... i tried several solutions but none worked so far. any idea / help? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to work with the instance and not pass on things in the morph function directly, that takes properties to morph and it probably runs your function immediately in the hope it will return a property value. you can do `el.set('morph', {onComplete: hideImagefn})` before that and it will work but read on...

one way to do it is to set your morph options/instance once and work with it afterwards like so:

```
(function() {
    var img = document.id('myImage').set('morph', {
        duration: 500,
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.in,
        link: 'cancel',
        onStart: function() {
            this.element.setStyle('display', 'block');
        }
    }), fx = img.get('morph');

    // of you can just do var fx = new Fx.Morph(img, { options});

    document.id('myButton').addEvents({
        mouseenter: function(){
           fx.start({
                opacity: 1,
                top: -205
           });
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            fx.addEvent('complete', function() {
                this.element.setStyle('display', 'none');
                this.removeEvents('complete');
            }).start({
                opacity: 0,
                top: -175
           });
        }   
    });

})();
```

the start ensures its always visible when mouseovered, the link is cancel which means it will stop execution if you mouse out too early and if you do mouseout, it will then hide the image and remove the onComplete event so that if you show it once more, it stays visible when it comes into view.

if you don't plan on being able to bring it back you can clean-up better and even use event pseudos like `onComplete:once` etc - though thats part of Event.Pseudos from mootools-more.

in general - `.get`/`.set` morph is your setup. `el.morph()` passes values to `morphInstance.start()`

play here: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/NkNHX/

Comment: great stuff! works like a charm! a maybe silly question in your eyes: is there an advantage in using document.id('myButton') instead of $('myButton') ?

Comment: yes. this is what $ references and by using document.id, you ensure that your code will work even if something like jquery gets added to the page without a `noConflict` hook.